# How to delete historical SQL server database snapshot

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-devops, snapshot

I have a CI/CD pipeline that creates a snapshot every time it's run. Now I want to achieve something like Delete all previous snapshots and create the new one or maybe I want to delete all previous backups and save the last two or three recent snapshots only.

I have created a snapshot with the name by appending the timestamp.

As of now, I am able to find only one command which is ***drop database snapshot name*** so not sure whether it's even possible to delete all historical snapshots somehow...

Edit :

Running below code does the kind of require job any idea how can I translate the same into PowerShell script so that I can run into pipeline?

```
DECLARE @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+ name + ']; ' FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%Dev%' FOR XML PATH('')) EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: sys.databases contains the snapshots - you can find them by filtering for source_database_id is not null which is FK back to the original database. in sys.databases.

Comment: Thanks.. this line does the job in sql server window .......DECLARE @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+ name + ']; ' FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%Dev%' FOR XML PATH('')) EXEC sys.sp_executesql  Sql           Any idea how can i run the same powershell

Comment: Not a powershell user but some simple searching finds many answers to most questions - try giving that a shot. And FWIW a single post should ask a single question and not evolve over time as you change the goal.

Comment: @SMor Sure.Thanks